# express: command not found after installing express-generator@4

Tags: node.js, express

getting below error every time I type express-h just after installing express-generator ..

```
roush@DESKTOP-E5Q8F9C MINGW64 /e/rpt/shopping-cart
$ npm install -g express-generator
C:\Users\roush\AppData\Roaming\npm\express -> C:\Users\roush\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express-generator\bin\express-cli.js
+ express-generator@4.16.0
updated 1 package in 2.019s

roush@DESKTOP-E5Q8F9C MINGW64 /e/rpt/shopping-cart
$ express
bash: express: command not found

roush@DESKTOP-E5Q8F9C MINGW64 /e/rpt/shopping-cart
$ npm install -g express-generator@4
C:\Users\roush\AppData\Roaming\npm\express -> C:\Users\roush\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express-generator\bin\express-cli.js
+ express-generator@4.16.0
updated 1 package in 1.42s

roush@DESKTOP-E5Q8F9C MINGW64 /e/rpt/shopping-cart
$ express
bash: express: command not found
```

Comment: Do you perhaps need to put an additional directory in your path?

Comment: No, as for now i had never set any path for anything in node. But the path where express generator is getting installed is physically not present in my drive.

Comment: Thanks. I assume the install process has a log? Could you edit the question to include the relevant lines from that please.

Comment: Hi Mandy, m not sure where to get the logs for the same could you please help here again.

Comment: I don't know, sorry, hopefully an expert will pick this up.